# Android jni calling java instance method fails silently

Tags: java-native-interface

I am calling a jar package from a so package. The jar, albeit using complicated layered structure with new abstraction/object/thread define and instantiation, gets packaged well and exposes a very narrow interface to the outside. I believe this is a common scenario.

I am making one-way invocation from jni code (in one of my pthread) in so to java code in jar. What I expect is call the narrow interface with the jar, and the jar does all and return.

Right now I can successfully call to instance method w/ argument passed. However, it failed silently if the method I call creates a new object, like this:

Java code:

```
public void AAA(){
    Log.i(...); <-----------------Successful
    new BBB(this); <--------------Don't know what happened
    Log.i(...); <-----------------Not successful
}
```

I put some print as the first line of BBB's constructor, it did NOT come out.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is BBB has a handler declared inside, but the thread instantiating BBB (said jni pthread) does not have an Android looper prepared. Add following code upon entering and exiting the thread:

Entering: 
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cLooper, mPrepare);
Exiting: 
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cLooper, mLoop);

Of course you should also prepare cLooper, env, method ID and so on in your native code somewhere.